# UIImage view picture title in uibutton

Tags: iphone, ios, uiimageview, uibutton

In my application i am having 1 image view and 4 buttons, i want to show the image name in one  of the button title,the remaining 3 button should show other titles,here my code code ,its not working,Please help me to solve

```
-(IBAction)answersetting:(id)sender
{
UIButton *mybutton = (UIButton *)sender;
static int j = 0;
if(sender == mybutton)
    j++;
if (j >= arcount)
{
    j = 0;
}
else if(j < 0)
{
    j = arcount - 1;
}
animage.image=[arimage objectAtIndex:j];
for(UIView *view in self.view.subviews)
{
    if([view isKindOfClass:[UIButton class]])
    {
        UIButton *button = (UIButton *)view;
        if(button.tag == 1||button.tag == 2||button.tag == 3||button.tag == 4)
        {
            int value = rand() % ([artext count] -1) ;
            NSMutableDictionary *dictionary = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc]init];
            [dictionary setValue:@"imageName" forKey:@"button"];
            [button setTitle:[artext objectAtIndex:value] forState:UIControlStateNormal];

        }
    }
}

}
```

Comment: UIButton *mybutton = (UIButton *)sender;
..if(sender == mybutton)
I think this if statement is useless.

Comment: @KevinCao i used it for showing next image on click

Comment: @fasilmoham: could you make your question more clear ?

Comment: in my view im having 1 image view and 4 buttons,i showed images in image view from an array,since i want to show the 1 button title as current image name,remaining button as diffrent name in the array. i could nt able to show the image current image name in button title,can yu pls help me to solve @VenkatManohar

Comment: @fasilmoham: what should be the button title..Like you are saving image name somewhere else ?

Comment: @VenkatManohar i just to show the button title as current image view image name from the array

Answer (score 2, accepted):

instead of:

```
[button setTitle:[artext objectAtIndex:value] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

try this:

```
[button setTitle:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[artext objectAtIndex:value]] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

also make sure `[artext objectAtIndex:value]` does contain some value.

Comment: superb,its working the problem is its coming like this `<UIImage: 0x7577460>`,how can i get exact word